# TPL - Difference between MaxDegreeOfParallelism and MaximumConcurrencyLevel

Tags: .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

What's the difference between `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism` and `ParallelOptions.TaskScheduler.MaximumConcurrencyLevel`?  When would you use either?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using reflector, I've gathered that both are used in `EffectiveMaxConcurrencyLevel` property:

```
internal int EffectiveMaxConcurrencyLevel
{
    get
    {
        int maxDegreeOfParallelism = this.MaxDegreeOfParallelism;
        int maximumConcurrencyLevel = this.EffectiveTaskScheduler.MaximumConcurrencyLevel;
        if ((maximumConcurrencyLevel > 0) && (maximumConcurrencyLevel != 0x7fffffff))
        {
            maxDegreeOfParallelism = (maxDegreeOfParallelism == -1) ? maximumConcurrencyLevel : Math.Min(maximumConcurrencyLevel, maxDegreeOfParallelism);
        }
        return maxDegreeOfParallelism;
    }
}
```